# Load cell, help

Tags: sensor, amplifier, adc, analog, load

I am using load cell, [from here](http://www.evelta.com/industrial-control/sensors/load-cell/czl-601-load-cell-80-kg). Load cell specification are mentioned on the site. 5 wire coming out, its a 4 wire core shielded load cell.

I can't get the same voltage value from +Signal and -Signal.

###What I am using:

- Using arduino nano runs on 5 V.
- Supplied excitation voltage : 4.78 V ~(From USB).
- Have not grounded Shield wire.(floating)(required to ground?).
- Using AD622 ina, connected REF voltage = VCC.
- Using MCP3551 ADC, connected -Vin Voltage = GND.

###After checking from multimeter:

- (+ and - signal) from Load cell: reading: 2.45v. both giving the same with respect to ground.
- Ad622 6th pin, OUT pin, gives me 4.08v at 60-70 ohms. (using potentiometer).
- This OUT pin is attached to MCP3551 2nd Pin, .i.e +Vin.
- Readings are coming from MCP3551 are noise data i guess, in bytecode
  What else I can do to detect the fault.
- Below is code sketch

```
        
    #include 
    #include 
    
    #define SS 10
    
    float fRawData;
    MCP3551 MCP_ADC(SS);
    
    void setup(){
      pinMode( SS, OUTPUT );
       
      // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println("Setup done.");
    }
    
    float getRawData(){
      double fVar = 0;
      int i = 0;
      bool isReady = MCP_ADC.getCode();
      if( isReady ){
        Serial.print("Raw data:");
        Serial.print(MCP_ADC.byteCode, DEC);
        Serial.println();
        
      }
    }
    
    void loop(){
      getRawData();
    }
```

#### Where is the fault. What factor / point I should consider to troubleshoot this up?

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffgkWB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please check the schematic. Please ask me, if something is not clear in the picture.

Comment: AD622 ref pin to Vcc? That doesn't sound right. What is Vcc? Is it arduino bias, or USB voltage, or Vs for AD622?

Comment: Can you draw some schematics?

Comment: How much noise you have? 22bit ADC is too good for circuits with potentiometers anywhere. With 22 bits you have 1uV resolution... Noise will fully cover few lowest bits. You may try to get 14-16 bit resolution.

Comment: AD622 ref pin to VCC, that is, my arduino nano is powered from USB. so i am taking USB's 5 volt to AD622 ref.

Comment: Tying Vref high is your first problem. Consult the datasheet on driving it properly.

Comment: You realize that the voltage difference between the load cell outputs is very small, don't you? You need to be measuring single millivolts accurately to see it.

Comment: How that load cell works? It's bidirectional source? What is presented at its output? What voltage range?

Comment: You wrote "What screwing thing i am facing is: Getting same voltage value from +Signal and -Signal." If you're measuring with no strain on the load cell, this is correct and to be expected. Even with strain, the difference will be small and may not show up on a multimeter. The load cell is basically a wheatstone bridge and produces a very small difference between +Signal and -Signal in response to strain. That's why you need a very high gain differential amplifier after it to get a useful signal.

Answer (score 2):

So far I found 1 mistake in your design.

**50ohm pot is too small (Rg value)**

AD622 instrumentation amplifier gain range is 2 to 1000.

**Your Ref pin at AD622 looks wrong**

Typically that pin is connected to ground (for measuring positive voltages) or to Vcc/2 voltage for measuring positive and negative voltages.

**Your Ref pin at ADC looks wrong**

It should be connected to voltage reference (or Vcc).

[image]

Voltage at noniverting AD622 pin should be above or same as at inverting pin, because in-amp cant process negative differential voltage without double supply (with negative below GND).

I never had to do with such load cells, I have no idea what kind of output they have, but 4 wire connection looks like some bridge sensing.

For bridge sensing you may need negative voltage source to handle negative voltage from bridge. In-amp can't process any negative voltages at any pin if it has no negative voltage provided. I don't know if you want to measure also negative load... If you dont - maybe there is no need for negative supply.

Comment: 50 ohms, in ad622 datasheet. to gain 1000, it should be near to 50 ohms. Sorry , actually Ref pin of ADC, mcp3551 in my board, i have connected it to vcc with caps. Okay , so let me check by putting AD622 REF to ground to get positive voltages.

Comment: @anny see my updated answer.

Comment: I did make changes, but problems remains, actually, the + signal and - signal coming are not changing, means, i am not getting any variation from there while putting load. As measured from multimeter. So rest of the part are just showing values based on the coming volts from ina and adc. So problem is why +sig n - sig are not changing. Is my load cell is not good/ or wrecked?

Comment: Sig+ and sig- is probably output from bridge... That bridge is powered? Datasheet says 12V, you wrote something about 4.8V. That is your cell input voltage?

Comment: Yes, 4.8v Is my load cell excitation voltage i am providing as i have to rum my whole setup over USB only. Yes, my load cell was powered. I also tried with 9.7 V battery,what i found after is +sig and -sig are again on same voltage and each of them at 9.7 v with respect to ground. I  suspect my load cell is not functioning properly.

Comment: @Anny notice that bridge sensor has very very little output, thats why in-amp is needed. It's more likely, that you messed up with in-amp pins or something like that.

Comment: yes something is messed up here. i understand why an op amp or ina stuff are used, but to check any load cell is working or not there are way around. but i am not able to verify that load cell is fine or not.  am sure that ina and adc are working fine and they will show some variation if any load is applied on load cell but they arn't showing such variations. Such a simple project is eating me.

Comment: What's the difference between Sig+ and Sig-?  Measured to ground they should be about Vcc/2, but differentially, they might change by about Vcc/1000 at full load versus no load.  Sig+ = Sig- = Vexcite+ means that the Vexcite- is open circuited/not connected to ground.